# Add Firebug Lite to JSFiddle to start up minimized

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle, minimize, minimized, firebug-lite

[Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) was best development tool for web for a long time. Now that advanced well-equipped Developer Tool is shifted with every major browsers, we don't need to look for it. But sometimes while sharing [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) code that prints some log to `console`, or just need peeking into html `attributes` or `classnames`, it seems more convenient to me to just include the [Firebug script](https://getfirebug.com/firebuglite#Stable) to the fiddle rather than bringing up the whole developer tools.

But when I add [Firebug Lite](https://getfirebug.com/firebuglite#Stable) to [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/), it starts up like this blocking most if not entire output frame. On my laptop it blocks the whole frame.

[image: SJFiddle Firebug Normal Window]

How can I include [Firebug Lite](https://getfirebug.com/firebuglite#Stable) to [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) that starts up in minimized mode, like as the bottom horizontal bar when it is minimised or like the small square on bottom-right corner in this image?

[image: JSFiddle Firebug Lite Minimized Window Mode]

Comment: Can I ask why are you using firebug? Just curious why

Comment: Because I am used to it, and sometimes it is needed to inspect elements or view the console.

Comment: Learn the use the built in tools, there is a reason why they stopped developing it. :) Does it have a flag to toggle the view, been years since I used that.

Comment: You obviously talk about Firebug Lite (the JavaScript snippet), so I've adjusted your question accordingly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this code snippet in HTML to minimize Firebug Lite in JSFiddle:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    firebug.env.height = 200;
    firebug.env.debug= false;   
    firebug.env.detectFirebug = true;  
</script>
```

Refer to http://jsfiddle.net/elijahmanor/UYK9G/ for more details.